# Веб-разработка на python

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать изучение python (web-разработка) если я недавно начал программировать, то есть ничего не знаю

Comment: [http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) / [http://djbook.ru/](http://djbook.ru/) - книга (пусть и подустаревшая) по джанге, самому крупному python-фреймворку.

Comment: @Etki Zope снисходительно смотрит на ваше убеждение о «самом крупном» %)

Comment: для веб-разработки  можно начать с html/css/javascript без серверной части на Питоне. Неплохая книжка: "JavaScript. The Good Parts / JavaScript. Сильные стороны". Рекомендуемая общая статья: [Научитесь программировать за десять лет](http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html) и [большинство книг из этого списка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо подтянуть свои знания по Python (если вы совсем ничего не знаете).
Воспользуйтесь интерактивными курсами для этого:
[Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python), [JetBrains (PyCharm Edu)](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-educational/?fromMenu). Так же рекомендую к изучению [Python 3 для начинающих и чайников](http://pythonworld.ru/).
Только после изучения основ следует браться за веб разработку. (Например используя [Django](http://djbook.ru/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)..)

Answer (score 0):

Учите сначала язык, потом фреймворки.

Подборка литературы на хабре - http://habrahabr.ru/post/150302/