# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python

Tags: python, книги, faq, python-faq

Рекомендуемая литература, курсы и документация по Python.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: это вопрос-замена всех старых обсуждений?

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, да, каноничный faq. Если есть чем поделиться (книги, курсы, небольшие аннотации) - вопрос общий - смело досыпай в ответ.

Comment: Довольно большой список книг можно найти на сайте [Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBooks), но не знаю, по какому принципу их стоит сюда переносить

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, я добавлял в список то, что советуют люди тут и в рунете. И что не совсем протухло по году выпуска.

Comment: Ещё я заметил, что вместо создания канонических вопросов-ответов в исходном SO размещают эту информацию в [описании метки](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info). Надо понять, какой способ лучше

Answer (score 135, accepted):

## Начинающим

- [Официальная документация](https://www.python.org/doc/)
- [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - рекомендации по оформлению кода

  - [Русский перевод на pythonworld.ru](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)
  - [Русский перевод на pep8.ru](https://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/)
- *Learning Python (5th Edition)*. Mark Lutz

  - Русский перевод: *Изучаем Python*. Марк Лутц.
- *Programming in Python 3: A Complete Introduction to the Python Language*. Mark Summerfield

  - Русский перевод: *Программирование на Python 3. Подробное руководство*. Марк Саммерфилд.
- *Python Crash Cource (3rd Edition)*. Eric Matthes.

  - Русский перевод: *Изучаем Python: программирование игр, визуализация данных, веб-приложения. 3-е изд.*  Мэтиз Э.
- *Python Essential Reference (4th Edition)*. David M. Beazley.

  - Русский перевод: *Python. Подробный справочник.*  Дэвид Бизли.
- *Dive Into Python 3*. Mark Pilgrim.

  - Русский перевод: [*Погружение в Python 3*](https://pep8.ru/doc/dive-into-python-3/) Марк Пилгрим.
- *Learn Python the Hard Way: A Very Simple Introduction to the Terrifyingly Beautiful World of Computers and Code (3rd Edition).*  Zed A. Shaw.
- *Простой Python. Современный стиль программирования*. Билл Любанович, O'Reilly (в переводе изд. Питер), 2016, 480 стр.
- *Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner*. Michael Dawson

  - Русский перевод: *Программируем на Python.* Майкл Доусон.
- [Набор статей по Python 3 на русском](https://python-scripts.com) *(python-scripts.com)*. Большой минус - реклама, занимающая до половины полезного пространства.
- [Обзорная статья по Python на русском](https://professii.su/programmirovanie/python-razrabotchik.html) *(professii.su)*. Много интересных фактов и учебных материалов для самостоятельного изучения.
- [Python 3 для начинающих](https://pythonworld.ru) *(pythonworld.ru)*
- Викиучебники:

  - [Python Programming](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming)
  - [Python - Викиучебник](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python)

    - [Объектно-ориентированное программирование на Python](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Python)
    - [Функциональное программирование на Python](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Python)
- [Уроки по языку программирования Python](https://devpractice.ru/python-lessons/) *(devpractice.ru)*

## Средний уровень

- *Python in Practice: Create Better Programs Using Concurrency, Libraries, and Patterns (Developer's Library)*. Mark Summerfield.

  - Русский перевод: *Python на практике*. Марк Саммерфилд.
- *Fluent Python*. Luciano Ramalho

  - Русский перевод: *Python. К вершинам мастерства*. Рамальо Лучано.
- *Core Python: Application Programming*. Wesley J Chun

  - Русский перевод: *Python. Создание приложений*. Уэсли Дж. Чан.
- [Python для сетевых инженеров](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/contents.html) - книга по основам Python в формате readthedocs. Несмотря на название подходит не только сетевым инженерам. Радует лаконичным оформлением и отсутствием рекламных баннеров.

## Онлайн-курсы

- [Stepik: Программирование на Python](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Python-67/) - базовый курс, рассматриваются самые основы языка
- [Stepik: Python: основы и применение](https://stepik.org/course/Python-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-512) - можно рассматривать как продолжение предыдущего курса, вводится ООП, итераторы, ФП, обработка данных на практике
- [Stepik: Адаптивный тренажер Python](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80-Python-431) - набор задач разного уровня сложности, курс подстраивается под уровень ученика
- [Stepik: Python. Functional Programming](https://stepik.org/course/Python-Functional-Programming-2057/) *(на английском)* - курс содержит теорию по [*функциональному программированию*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и набор задач, предполагающих решение в функциональном стиле.
- [Stepik: Практикум по математике и Python](https://stepik.org/course/3356) - есть вводный блок по основам Python, математические задачи (на теорию чисел, и др.), обработка данных с помощью numpy, pandas (есть блоки заданий для тренировки), визуализация с помощью matplotlib, seaborn, оптимизация и матричные разложения, основы теории вероятностей и статистики, дополнительные темы (JSON, Requests, API)
- [Stepik: Python для решения практических задач](https://stepik.org/course/4519) - курс в основном ориентирован на получение и обработку данных с внешних источников: рассматривается обработка веб-страниц, работа с веб-сервисами через REST API (модуль requests), работа с электронными таблицами (excel), XML, json, основы визуализации с помощью pyplot, публикация на сервере в виде html страниц
- [Udacity: Programming Foundations with Python](https://www.udacity.com/course/programming-foundations-with-python--ud036)
- [Udacity: Developing Scalable Apps in Python](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-scalable-apps-in-python--ud858)
- [Udacity: Design of Computer Programs](https://www.udacity.com/course/design-of-computer-programs--cs212) - курс по программированию с интересными задачами, теория + практика Python.
- [Codecademy: Python](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python) - курс самого базового уровня, задания вида "повтори то что тебе только что показали"
- [Udemy: Automate the Boring Stuff with Python Programming](https://www.udemy.com/automate/) - автоматизация рутинных действий с помощью Python (курс платный)
- [Специализация "Python для всех" на Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/python)

## Онлайн-ресурсы, ориентированные на решение задач

- [checkio.org](http://www.checkio.org/) - хороший ресурс с задачами, на котором можно даже получить комментарий от Гвидо ван Россума. Процесс решения геймифицирован.
- [projecteuler.net](https://projecteuler.net/) - сайт с набором задач различной сложности, можно решать на разных языках программирования, в том числе на Python
- [codecombat.com](https://codecombat.com/) - rpg, для прохождения которой надо писать код на Python.
- [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) - много задач разного уровня, можно выбрать язык программирования, в том числе есть Python.
- [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) - решаешь задачи на разных языках программирования и одновременно прокачиваешь своё резюме.
- [codingame](https://www.codingame.com/) - учишься программировать, выполняя интересные миссии, составляя ботов и соревнуясь с другими участниками в программировании на скорость.
- [1000+ проектов для начинающих](https://reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2a9ygh/1000_beginner_programming_projects_xpost/) - ветка из  r/learnprogramming subreddit.
- [Hyperskill](https://hyperskill.org) - сайт с проектами для обучения программированию на Java, Kotlin, Python. Есть интеграция с [Educational](https://www.jetbrains.com/education/) версиями продуктов JetBrains. Раздел по Python пока в разработке.
- [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/) - много задач, разбитых на три категории сложности. По подписке можно получить информацию о том, в каких компаниях на собеседованиях встречаются представленные задачи.

## Видеокурсы

- [Программирование на Python](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpTTNp7HBYzCBByaE1h54ruW) - курс лекций от Computer Science Center
- [Алгоритмы и структуры данных на Python](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRDzFCPr95fK7tr47883DFUbm4GeOjjc0) - лекции МФТИ

---

## Библиотеки для реализации графического интерфейса (GUI)

### PyQT

- *PyQt. Создание оконных приложений на Python 3*. Н.А. Прохоренко.
- *Introduction to Python Programming and Developing GUI Applications with PyQT*. B. M. Harwani.
- [PyQt5 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) *(англ.)*

  - [Перевод нескольких примеров](https://pythonworld.ru/gui)

### Python GTK

- [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) *(англ.)*

### Tkinter

- [Раздел документации Python 3 по Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) *(англ.)*
- [tkinterbook](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) (An Introduction to Tkinter) *(англ.)* ([архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/))
- [wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) *(англ.)*
- [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) *(англ.)*
- [Курс по библиотеке Tkinter языка Python](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5_Tkinter_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_Python) (Викиверситет)
- [GUI Help/Tkinter book](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/GUI_Help/Tkinter_book) (викиучебник)
- [Серия статей по tkinter на сайте PythonRu.com](https://pythonru.com/tag/tkinter)
- [python-scripts.com: Ознакомление с Tkinter](https://python-scripts.com/tkinter-introduction) (примеры избыточны, сразу вводится ООП, поэтому не всегда подходит новичкам)

### wxPython

- [Официальный сайт](https://wxpython.org)
- [Документация](https://docs.wxpython.org) (на английском)
- [wxPython in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/wxpython-in-action) Noel Rappin and Robin Dunn, March 2006  ISBN 9781932394627, 584 pages

  - [Частичный перевод](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/WxPythonInAction) (на момент добавления записи переведено 14 из 18 глав)

### Kivy

- [Kivy wiki](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki) *(англ.)* - коллекция полезной информации по Kivy
- [Getting started](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/intro.html) *(англ.)* - официальное руководство
- *Kivy: Interactive Applications in Python*. Roberto Ulloa
- [Статьи по Kivy на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/search/?target_type=posts&q=%5Bkivy%5D&order_by=date)

---

## Веб-фреймворки

### Django

- [Официальная документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com) (на английском)

  - Перевод документации Django 3: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/
- *Web Development with Django Cookbook*. Aidas Bendoraitis.
- *Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices For Django 1.6*. Daniel Greenfeld, Audrey Roy.
- [Курс Django Girls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/)
- [Веб-фреймворк Django (Python)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django)
- *Django 2.1. Практика создания веб-сайтов на Python, Дронов В.А, 2019* (книга на русском)

### Flask

- [Официальная документация](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (на английском)

  - [Перевод документации](https://flask-russian-docs.readthedocs.io)
- [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) от Miguel Grinberg

  - Перевод на Хабре:

    - [Мега-Учебник Flask](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193242/)
    - [Мега-Учебник Flask (издание 2018)](https://habr.com/post/346306/)

### FastAPI

- [Официальная документация](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com) (на английском)
- [Официальная документация](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ru/) (на русском)
- [Хабр: Знакомство с FastAPI](https://habr.com/ru/post/488468/)

Comment: Появилась неплохая книга "Python 3 и PyQt 5. Разработка приложений"

Comment: HackerRank - ресурс с задачами не только на питоне - грех не вспомнить.

Comment: https://www.talentbuddy.co/ недоступен, кто-нибудь знает, это временно или умер ресурс?

Comment: @dred https://twitter.com/talentbuddy/status/700343814117068801

Comment: В раздел "Начинающим" можно добавить курсы на Степике серии "Поколение Python".

Comment: предлагаю добавить https://riptutorial.com/python - сборник примеров

Comment: А есть что-то для программиста на С++? В смысле, если человек хорошо знает С++, как ему перейти на Python...

Comment: Интересно, я на checkio аж 20 уровень набрал, а "комментария от Гвидо ван Россума" так и не дождался...