# Нужны задачи по пайтону!

Tags: python

Всем привет!Недавно начал изучать пайтон.Посоветуйте сайты с задачами для начинающих по данном языке!

Comment: по-моему, самый лучший способ выучить питон - это попробовать отвечать на [вопросы по питону](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Заодно английский можно подучить/вспомнить...

Comment: Я за всю жизнь не решал ни одну задачу по программированию, созданную именно как "задача для обучения" (разве что случайно, ответив на какой нибудь учебный вопрос тут :) ). Придумайте что бы хотели сделать, может оно даже достаточно сложное. И начните это делать, по немногу, по шагам. Как наткнетесь на то что не получается, постарайтесь найти решение, погуглите, в крайнем случае (если вопрос не стандартный и поисковики/литература не помогают) задайте вопрос здесь.

Comment: Если очень хочеться, то можно посмотреть - https://checkio.org/ - http://www.pythonchallenge.com/

Comment: http://www.codewars.com/

Comment: Есть hackerrank, хороший ресурс с задачами не только на питоне.

Comment: @s.gaynetdinov такие вопросы тут - оффтопик. если хотите - допишите ссылки в общий ответ - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420126/177221