# Что делать новичку Python? Как тренироваться?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я начал недавно(месяц назад) изучать программирование. Столкнулся с такой проблемой что не знаю что делать из практики какие задания придумывать. Как тренироваться ? Подкиньте пару заданий для новичка.
(Я сделал подобие калькулятора в терминале)

Comment: Вам следует конкретизировать Ваш вопрос.

Comment: https://checkio.org/ тут есть задачи от начального до высокого уровня

Comment: К сожалению, подобные вопросы - оффтопик на SO, т.к. они приводят к закидыванию ссылками на внешние ресурсы, причем каждый раз - одними и теми же ссылками. Исключение сделано только для общего вопроса [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125). В котором, кстати, есть почти все ссылки, что вам набросали ниже.

Answer (score 7):

Добавлю сюда ещё несколько ресурсов с интересными задачами для начинающих питонистов:

1. [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) - много клёвых задач разного уровня, можно выбрать язык программирования.
2. [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) - решаешь задачи на разных языках и одновременно прокачиваешь своё резюме.
3. [checkio](https://checkio.org/) - уже писали про него, много клёвых задач с элементами игрофикации.
4. [codecombat](https://codecombat.com/play) - программирование игрового персонажа в ролевой игре.

Comment: В wiki-вопросе [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/) есть общий список тренировочных ресурсов, стоит добавить в него ссылки из вашего ответа.

Comment: Спасибо @PashaPash. Добавил ссылочки в wiki-статью, про которую ты написал.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете пройти один из многочисленных курсов по питону. [Например](http://pythontutor.ru/). Также, вас могут сильно прокачать [олимпиадные задачи](http://acm.timus.ru/?locale=ru) ([тут](http://informatics.mccme.ru/) и [тут](http://codeforces.com/)) как по скорости написания кода, так и сложности написания кода. Но нужно понимать, что такого вида задачи могут давать о себе знать при написании качественного кода.