# Python: Как передать значение переменной одной функции другой функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Первая функция `text()` возвращает строку с сайта, сохраняя эту строку как значение переменной `а`. Я пытаюсь значение переменной `a` использовать в другой функции `rs()`. Цель - сохранить эту строку в текстовый файл. Я понимаю, что у второй функции нет доступа к переменной первой функции, но я не понимаю, как можно это исправить.

```
import requests
import re
def text():
    s = requests.get('http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1342.txt.utf-8').text
    a = '\n'.join(re.split(r'\W+', s.lower()))
    return a

def rs():
    f = open("f.txt", "w")
    f.write(a)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Если вы не знаете что функции в Питоне могут аргументы принимать, то вам стоит прочесть любую [книгу по Питону](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/23044), чтобы хотя бы начальное представление получить что доступно в языке, иначе вы можете потерять много времени на простейших вопросах.

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример:

```
def foo_1():
    var = 'hello world'
    return var

def foo_2(arg):
    print(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo_2(foo_1())
```

Функция `foo_1` вернула нам переменную var в которой записано `'hello world'`, далее мы вызываем функцию `foo_2` и передаём ей 1 аргумент, а именно то что вернёт нам функция `foo_1`.

Получим результат:

```
hello world
```

Подробнее о функциях и их аргументах [читайте тут](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html).

Answer (score 0):

Напишите:

```
rs():
    i = text()
```

в `i` будет лежать передаваемая переменная.