# Изучения Python

Tags: python

**Добрый день, всем!**
Подскажите пожалуйста, решил изучить Python,
как лучше всего изучить?
подскажите пожалуйста ресурсы, может кто так же начинал.
В данный момент уровень знания html css

Answer (score 0):

Марк Лутц "Изучаем Python" - лучший выбор.

[Официальная документация](http://docs.python.org/) по языку Python.

[Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Для совсем базовых знаний пойдёт что-то [такое](http://pythontutor.ru/). Также есть очень хороший [курс](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpTTNp7HBYzCBByaE1h54ruW) записанный [CSC](http://compsciclub.ru/)

Ну и также не стоит забывать про [официальную документацию](https://www.python.org/doc/)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Для понимания ООП будет полезно написать несколько простых игр на Tkinter.
Особенно хорошо помогает понять ООП написание шутера (вид сверху) с различными видами оружия, пуль, блоков, врагов, неподвижных предметов.

Comment: понял учту спасибо!