# Как понять, где закончилась функция в Python?

Tags: python, функции

Решил изучить Python, и назрел такой вопрос: как понять, когда заканчивается функция в нем? Ведь в других ЯП все просто - {}, или begin-end.

Comment: Есть отступы. Где отступы на одном уровне с объявлением функции, значит это уже конец

Comment: Начните с книги [Программирование на Python 3. Подробное руководство](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4562082/). Там буквально в начале про это написано.

Comment: Или скоро курс «Программирование на Python» от МФТИ на https://www.coursera.org/ запустится — теоретическая часть на сколько я понимаю будет доступна как и у многих курсов бесплатно. Очень хороший курс.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: def firstFunc():
   ...:     print('Im here!')
   ...: print('Этот принт уже не входит в функцию')
```

Как видим последний `print()` уже не в функции, так как он вне её тела.

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python) Вы найдете литературу по Python.