# Как научиться программировать на Python

Tags: python

Несколько дней назад начал изучать питон через андроид приложение Sololearn, и даже получил их сертификат об прохождении курса. Но проблема в том, что я как не умел программировать, так и не умею, а курс уже закончился.

Куда двигаться дальше? Какие материалы изучать? Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Есть же гугл, ютуб и тонны книг, вы ж даже не искали.

Comment: для начала вот эти два текста [ask] и [tour]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего начать с данных книг:

1. марк лутц изучаем python 4-е издание,
2. марк лутц программирование на python том 1,
3. марк лутц программирование на python том 2,
4. python создание приложений уэсли дж чан,
5. автостопом по python кеннет рейтц.

После прочтения данных книг все вопросы типа что учить дальше и т.д. отпадут сами собой.
Главное не смотрите всякого рода видео курсы и т.д., я лично их иногда вместо камеди клаб смотрю.

Comment: спасибо. уже слышал про эту книгу!

Answer (score 0):

если ест английский язык,тогда советую эту книгу:
[https://www.amazon.com/Python-Crash-Course-Hands-Project-Based/dp/1593276036/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1504090428&sr=8-2&keywords=python](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593276036)

Comment: спасибо за совет, но английский плохо знаю:(

Comment: тогда это для вас:
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137673590/

Comment: клево, спасибо!