# Python - фрейморки , плагины

Tags: python, framework

Я хочу стать так называемым "белым хакером" . Можете подсказать , какие знания мне нужны будут в языке python . Основы языка я знаю (прочитал Марка Лутца) , но вот теперь не знаю что мне учить . Возможно, подскажите какие фреймоврки или плагины которые стоит выучить,так как одного питона не хватит , что бы сказать что я могу работать хорошо с базами  данных , прочими хакерскими вещами .

Comment: Думаю что вам для этого дела понадобиться более низкоуровневый язык, на Си очень удобно заниматься тем чем вы планируете, а Python он для других задач.

Comment: А какие ещё языки можете посоветовать?

Comment: Лучше чем Си для ваших целей нет ничего, я по крайне мере не знаю таких языков.

Comment: Я чёт не понял, как связаны базы данных и «белые хакеры»? А вообще вопрос не подходит по формату для ruSO

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч: авторы [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) не согласны, что Питон для других задач создан

Comment: @andreymal Разве умение работать с базами данных не нужна,это вроде очень важно особенно white hat-у ?

Comment: @TarasYaitskiy любой hat должен понимать всё, не только базы. Непонятно, почему базы выделены как что-то особенное. Как, впрочем, и питон

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам Python и тем более фреймворки и плагины стать хакером не помогут, хотя их изучение и полезно для умения программировать. Поэтому берите книги по информационной безопасности (ИБиЗИ), компьютерным сетям, архитектуре компьютера, операционные системы (в т.ч. изучить линукс), желательно взять С++/Си (прочитать книги Рихтера по программированию в Windows), тестирование и администрированию. Но вообще это достаточно сложная ниша для изучения и требует очень больших усилий и навыков.

А так для начала попробуйте просто программировать, у нас есть [отличный раздел с книгами для Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python), который можете использовать и выбрать что-то оттуда.

Мне нравится цитата из книги "Борис Леонтьев - Хакеры, взломщики и другие информационные убийцы". Как раз из той оперы, как действует хакер, ведь по факту белые хакеры и специалисты по информационной безопасности делают одно и то же, только с разных этических сторон. Обратите внимание на раздел "дисциплины по программированию и вычислительной технике" и "специальные дисциплины".

Стать хакером очень просто. Достаточно выучить и понять:

- математические дисциплины

  - математический анализ
  - теория функций комплексного переменного
  - алгебра
  - геометрия
  - теория вероятностей
  - математическая статистика
  - математическая логика
  - дискретная математика
- инженерные дисциплины

  - физика
  - аппаратные средства вычислительной техники
  - основы радиоэлектроники
  - сети связи и защита информации от технической разведки
- дисциплины по программированию и вычислительной технике

  - информатика
  - языки программирования высокого уровня
  - методы программирования
  - язык ассемблера
  - операционные системы
  - системы управления базами данных и вычислительные сети
- специальные дисциплины

  - криптография
  - теоретические основы защиты компьютерных систем

Это достаточно полный список. Но если же говорить о более подробных хакерских вещах, то вам необходимо знать, что на свете существуют:

- криптографические методы в системах защиты государственной, конфиденциальной и - коммерческой информации.
- криптографические методы и средства защиты и дешифрования информации.
- математические методы расчета надежности шифрсистем.
- математические модели процессов, возникающие при защите информации.
- методы решения вероятностных, статистических и алгоритмических задач - криптографического анализа, синтеза шифрсистем и криптографических протоколов.
- методы определения угроз безопасности информации.
- методы построения математических моделей защищаемой информации, шифров и шифрсистем.
- методы преобразования информации в сетях различного типа.
- методы прогнозирования оценок криптографической стойкости.
- обеспечение надежности функционирования аппаратуры шифрования и тестирования программно-аппаратных реализаций криптографических алгоритмов.
- определение каналов утечки информации методикой измерения и расчета параметров опасных сигналов.
- основные положения теории электрических цепей.
- основные принципы организации систем и сетей связи и особенности современных сетевых архитектур.
- основные типы шифров, шифрсистем, криптографических протоколов и способы выбора системы защиты.
- особенности разработки и сопровождения программного обеспечения для рабочих групп и парапрограммирования.
- принципы построения шифров, шифрсистем и криптографических протоколов.
- типовые методы криптографического анализа и оценивания криптографической стойкости.

P.S. В любом случае, вы всегда можете стать просто хорошим программистом и не стремиться прыгнуть выше головы.

Comment: если вы находите подобные списки интересными, то можно погуглить: Mind map of information security

Comment: Для меня программисты делятся на два типа , которые как либо связаны с web'ом , или создают программы(игры и тд.) . Мне нравится программирование , но не нравится ни одна из выше перечисленных мною тем . И ещё , зачем нужен язык ассемблера?

Comment: @TarasYaitskiy еще есть разработчики баз данных, которые продумывают оптимальную и быструю архитектуру хранения различных данных. Язык ассемблера помогает понять как работает компьютер и программы на базовом уровне, а так же используется для реверс-инжиниринга и поиска уязвимостей различных декстопных программ. На данный момент Вам достаточно прочитать общую фундаментальную книгу Эндрю Таненбаум - "Архитектура компьютера", а так же у него есть книга по сетям "Компьютерные сети" и по ОС "Современные операционные системы".

Comment: @TarasYaitskiy но вообще относитесь к ответу, как к чему-то общему. Мне сложно указать какой-либо конкретный путь или навыки, так как с данной областью я знаком не сильно. В основном в институте на данном направлении упор приходился на изучение сетей, операционных систем и программирование на С++ и Руби(можно Python, кто-то учил Perl), много администрировали разное оборудование и сторонние программы.

Comment: @AlexKrass То есть , такой старый язык как ассемблер , ещё и используется в взломах ?????

Comment: @TarasYaitskiy учитывая, что ассемблер является языком процессора, что в этом удивительного? Любой язык в конечном счете превращается в инструкции на ассемблере и тот же Python не исключение, ведь его интерпретатор выполняет ассемблерные команды в итоге. До сих помню, как читал с удивлением [реверс-инжиниринг StarCraft 2](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2010/11/2.html) и [реверс-инжиниринг Diablo III](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157447/). Очень интересно, правда до сих пор больше половины изложенного в статьях не понимаю... Ну и картинки нынче уже для SC2 не грузятся почему-то(

Comment: Ассемблер используется как "багакопатель"  , а уже такие языки как C,C++ для самого взлома?