# Дан вложенный словарь. Вывести тип данных ключа и количество элементов в нем. в Python

Tags: python, словари

Дан словарь с элементами разных типов

```
{'в': 1, 7: [1,5], 'у': 'abc', '9': []}
```

Нужно вывести словарь вида

```
{имя_типа : количество_элементов_этого_типа}
```

Comment: Добавьте результат для приложенного вами словаря и, хорошо бы, пример ваших наработок

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
data = {'в': 1, 7: [1,5], 'у': 'abc', '9': []}
counter = Counter(type(v).__name__ for k, v in data.items())
print(dict(counter)) # преобразуем в обычный словарь для вывода в нужном формате.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# type str
type_str_val = 0

# type int
type_int_val = 0

# type float
type_float_val = 0

#type tuple
type_tuple_val = 0


# словарть который идет на выход, пока значение всех ключей None.
return_dict = {
    "type_int": None,
    "type_str": None,
    "type_float": None,
    "type_tuple": None,
}

slovar = {
    1: 10,
    2: 15,
    1.4: 4.5,
    "str": 'value',
    (1,): "typle",
    "value_list": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "value_dict": {1: 2, "str": "value_str"}
}

# приходим по словарю
for key, value in slovar.items():
    if type(key) == str:
        type_str_val += 1   # если есть ключ, то и есть значение.

    if type(key) == int:
        type_int_val += 1

    if type(key) == float:
        type_float_val += 1

    if type(key) == tuple:
        type_tuple_val += 1


# Обновляем словарть новыми значаниями
return_dict["type_int"] = type_int_val
return_dict["type_str"] = type_str_val
return_dict["type_float"] = type_float_val
return_dict["type_tuple"] = type_tuple_val


print(return_dict)
```

**Результат работы: 

  {'type_int': 2, 'type_str': 3, 'type_float': 1, 'type_tuple': 1}**

На будущее, список книг:
1) [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python) 
2) [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python/420126) 
3) [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: 1) Считаю что переменные типо type_str_val не нужны. Сразу в словаре заведите их `... "type_int": 0, ...`, а при обработке вместо `type_str_val += 1` будет `return_dict["type_str"] += 1` 2) Нужно подправить в ссылках название "введите сюда описание ссылки"

Comment: Да и так можно.

Comment: Можно и массив на 100 элементов заполнять на 100 строк по индексу, а лучше все-таки это делать цикле. Так и тут, если перенесете из переменных сразу в словарь, код сократится на 20 строк

Answer (score 0):

**Если же вам необходимо просто посчитать типы значений словаря *только* на первом уровне обратите внимание на [ответ godva](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803488/183429).**

Если я правильно понял то нам нужно узнать типы всех элементов как ключей так и значений, по этому для удобства переводим ключи и значения в линейный список.

Думаю разобраться в коде труда не составит. Из того что может не знать новичок здесь только `isinstance`сравнивающий класс переменной и передаваемого вторым аргументом класса, а так же `get` метод словаря возвращающий значение по ключу переданному первым аргументом или если ключа нет в словаре значение второго аргумента, либо None, если второго аргумента нет.

```
def inline_key_value_array(dic):
    # Помните, использование глобальных переменных внутри функций не лучшая практика.
    types[type(dic).__name__] = types.get(type(dic).__name__, 0) + 1

    result = []

    for key, value in dic.items():
        result.append(key)

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result += inline_key_value_array(value)

        elif isinstance(value, set) or isinstance(value, tuple) or isinstance(value, list):
            result += inline_value_array(value)

        else:
            result.append(value)

    return result

def inline_value_array(lst):
    # Помните, использование глобальных переменных внутри функций не лучшая практика.
    types[type(lst).__name__] = types.get(type(lst).__name__, 0) + 1

    result = []

    for value in lst:
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result += inline_key_value_array(value)

        elif isinstance(value, set) or isinstance(value, tuple) or isinstance(value, list):
            result += inline_value_array(value)

        else:
            result.append(value)

    return result

types = {}

input_dic = {'в': 1, 7: [1,5], 'у': {'в': 1, 7: [1,5], 'у': 'abc', '9': [1]}, '9': {2, 5}}

# Разворачием словарь в линейный список
input_list = inline_key_value_array(input_dic)

for i in input_list:
    # Получаем название типа и подставляем его как ключ. Так же используем .get на случай если значение словаря не объявлено. 
    types[type(i).__name__] = types.get(type(i).__name__, 0) + 1

print(types)
```