# Как можно используя цикл for, пройтись по массиву?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно используя цикл for рассмотреть каждый элемент масива. range почему-то не работает

Comment: а в учебниках что пишут?

Comment: В том по какому я занимаюсь ничего

Comment: @Бронеслав не занимайте по такому учебнику, возьмите [нормальный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420126/204271).

Comment: А какой нормальный?

Comment: @Бронеслав "Изучаем Python" Лутца.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирайте, что больше нравится:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# 1.
for item in items:
    print(item)

print()

# 2.
for i in range(len(items)):
    print(items[i])

print()

# 3.
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    print(i, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
b = []
n = 0
for a in range(1, N+1):
    b.append(int(input()))
for num in b:
    if num == 0:
        n+=1
print(n)
```

опытным путём

Comment: ``range(1, N+1)`` в данной случае эквивалетно ``range(N)``.

Comment: Можно так попробовать: `items = [int(input()) for _ in range(N)]` + `n = sum(num == 0 for num in items)` :)