# Что значит if element in (object1, object2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Что значит  if element in (object1, object2) ?

Comment: Существует ли element в кортеже (object1, object2).

Comment: Добавлю. `element` в данном случае это имя переменной. Оно может быть заменено на любое другое, приемлемое для Python, имя

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/1365) вам в помощь. Серьезно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как написали выше `Существует ли element в кортеже (object1, object2)`

Я решил привести пример

```
foo = 1

if foo in (2, 5):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
    

if foo in (1, 3):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Вывод

> No
>
> Yes

Answer (score 2):

Данная конструкция работает если указываемый объект имеет метод `__contains__()`. С помощью него определяется вхождение объекта чаще всего в некую последовательность

```
 |  __contains__(...)
 |      x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
```

Такой метод есть у списков и кортежей:

```
print(1 in [1,2])
print(1 in (1,2))
```

С помощью классов можно задать своё поведения для этой конструкции:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __contains__(self, item):
        if self.a*2 == item:
            res = True
        else:
            res = False
        return res

my = A(4)
print(8 in my)
# True
```