# Здравствуйте!Как запустить Python 3.6.3?

Tags: python, windows

Как запустить Python 3.6.3?Ответа в книжке я не нашёл.
Windows 10.

Comment: В какой книжке? Она по Python?

Comment: Да по Python 3.6.3. Автор:Кори Альтхофф.Название:#Сам себе программист

Comment: Что-то терзают сомнения. Я уже вторую книгу по Python читаю и там постоянно начинается все с установки Python

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/262779

Comment: В этой книге тоже.

Comment: Пройдите по ссылке, там достаточно литературы и ресурсов для обучению данному ЯП

Comment: Вот вам нормальный сайт, там есть туториал, коль серьезно взялись: https://www.python.org/ (Первоисточник)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первым делом нужно его скачать с официального сайта, установить.
Далее запустить его и писать код в консоли или создать файл с расширением `.py` и указать пути к нему.

Подробнее: [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMp0JtliEsU%5C)