# Простое шифрование слова на python

Tags: python, шифрование

Пишу простую программу шифрования строки.

Например: создать список или словарь (q,w,e,r,t,y1,2,3,4) символов, по которым и будет осуществляться шифрование.

Далее, как я понял, нужно реализовать сопоставление введенного слова с символами из списка/словаря, а затем выполнить замену символов и вывести результат на экран.

Но вот как это сделать?

Comment: [Учебник по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/204271) почитайте.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду создание словаря с значениями, то это можно сделать так:

```
dict_with_coding = {
                    'a' : 1,
                    'b' : 2,
                    'c' : 3 
}
```

И т.д. по списку. Можно также генерировать словарь с помощью модуля random.

Осуществить кодирование можно так(метод возвращает новую строку, поскольку строки в `Python` неизменяемые):

```
def code_string(input_str : str, coding_dict) -> str:

    #Получаем список символов
    list_with_symbols = list(input_str)

    for i in range(len(list_with_symbols)):
        #Этот фрагмент также можно реализовать с помощью метода dict.setdefault
        #чтобы исключить случаи отсутствия ключа в словаре
        list_with_symbols[i] = str(coding_dict[list_with_symbols[i]]) 

    return ''.join(sym for sym in list_with_symbols)
```

Проведём немного тестов:

```
dict_with_coding = {
                    'a' : 1,
                    'b' : 2,
                    'c' : 3 
}

print(code_string('aabbccc', dict_with_coding))
print(code_string('babcac', dict_with_coding))
print(code_string('cabcbab', dict_with_coding))
```