# Как заполнить массив числами от 1 до Н?

Tags: python

Я изучаю Python. К примеру я вожу число '5', мне должен вывести ответ '1 2 3 4 5', или вожу 3, тогда ответ '1 2 3'. Так так сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = input('Введите число: ')
nums = list(range(1, int(n) + 1))
print(*nums)
```

Крайне рекомендую [изучать по учебнику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/204271), так как для новичка очень важна правильная и систематизированная подача материала.

Comment: ' '.join(range(1, int(n) + 1))