# Изучение Django

Tags: python, django

Я новичок. Посоветуйте курсы/лекции/книги по Django, по которым учились вы. Ну или если вы просто слышали о хороших

Comment: [Официальная документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/).

Comment: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/

Comment: Хороший ресурс https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/

Comment: Я недавно начал изучение Django. Вообще использую курсы на ютубе, т.к они в открытом доступе. Но слышал про книгу Владимира Дронова по Django.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website

Comment: 2all, если хотите добавить ссылку на какой-то полезные ресурс, добавляйте его в ответ [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python), а не здесь в комментариях.