# zip_command, как она работает в данном коде

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кто сможет объяснить 6-ую строку данного кода?

```
1.import os
2.import time
3.source = ['"C:\Program Files\WinRAR"']
4.target_dir = 'D:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.
5.target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
6.zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
7.if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
8.    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
9.else:
10.    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строку на место `{0}` подставляется первый аргумент метода [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format), на место `{1}` второй, а потом получившаяся строка присваивается переменной `zip_command`.

Comment: а join(source) что именно делает в данном случае?

Comment: @ЕрасылТауланов вообще-вообще не хочется читать документацию, да? Грубо говоря, метод [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)  превращает значение переменной `source` в строку.

Comment: это я читал, но вот смотрите, у нас получается так: "zip -qr {target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'} {"C:\Program Files\WinRAR"} так же? И я понять не могу, что мы этим добились?

Comment: Что мешает вам между 6-й и 7-й строками вставить `print(zip_command)` и посмотреть на результат?

Comment: а вот этого я не знал)

Comment: то есть, он берет {1} и кидает (так сказать) его в {0} ?

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/204271).

Comment: Спасибо) простите)