# Не запускается сервер Django

Tags: python, django, eclipse, python-3.7

Начал изучать Django на Eclipse(PyDev). Система windous 10 Создал Джанго проект по инструкции. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске через Windous power shell выдаёт ошибку №2 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю откуда взялась, и как устранить. Ведь этот файл в той папке есть.

P.S. Заранее благодарен

Comment: manage.py в родительском каталоге есть, а не в том, где вы команду выполняете.

Comment: Я скопировал этот файл из родительского, и вставил на одну папку ниже.( В папку First_Dgango) Теперь выдаёт новую ошибку

Comment: Он должен лежать там, где лежал.

Comment: А как тогда запустить?

Comment: Перейти в каталог `E:\Учёба\developing\First_Django` и выполнить в нём `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: Чтобы стать django-разработчиком, надо сначала стать продвинутым пользователем ПК, уверенно работающим в консоли, потом хорошо [изучить Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/204271) и только после этого браться за [изучение Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/). Ваша проблема связана с тем, что вы перепрыгнули первый шаг. И скорее всего после запуска у вас вылезет ещё несколько ошибок, так как второй вы наверняка тоже перепрыгнули.

Comment: В интернете не нашёл курсов овладения компьютером до уровня "Продвинуты пользователь", с питоном знаком. Поэтому учусь на ходу используя все интернетовские доступные ресурсы.