# Где практиковать олимпиадное программирование?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Где можно попрактиковаться в решении олимпиадных задач по программированию?

Я пользуюсь сейчас Python, но позднее хотел  бы перейти и на другой язык, например,  С++ или Java.

Нуждаюсь в сайте где можно было бы решать задачи и после смотреть их решения

Comment: Нам в универе препод когда-то вот на [этот](http://pythontutor.ru) ссылку кидал

Comment: Сайт где можно было бы решать задачи и смотреть решения https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: Подобный функционал есть на [stepik](https://welcome.stepik.org/ru)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Есть сайт, на котором вы можете попрактиковать решение задач , написанных на питоне, сайт конкретно этому языку и посвящен

> https://pythontutor.ru/

Так же есть сайт для решения олимпиадных задач

Здесь вы найдете задачи не только для языка питон

> https://acmp.ru/

Также можете ознакомиться с этим ресурсом

> http://algolist.manual.ru/olimp/