# Повторения в массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-3.6

Выполняю задания с Проекта Эйлера, задание под номером 29.
Вопрос звучит:

> Сколько различных членов имеет последовательность a**b для 2 ≤ a ≤ 100 и 2 ≤ b ≤ 100?

Я построил алгоритм с помощью цикла while, однако обнаружил повторения чисел в массиве.

Мой код:

```
def func():
   new_list = []
   a = 2
   b = 2
   while (2 <= a <= 100) and (2 <= b <=100):
      new_list.append(a**b)
      b += 1
      if b == 101:
         b = 2
         a += 1

   new = sorted(new_list)
   return new

print(func())
```

В чем заключается моя ошибка, и как устранить данные повторения чисел в массиве?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы учитываете все элементы, включая дубликаты.

Например число `4096` является результатом следующих операций:

```
In [52]: 2**12
Out[52]: 4096

In [53]: 4**6
Out[53]: 4096

In [54]: 8**4
Out[54]: 4096

In [55]: 16**3
Out[55]: 4096

In [56]: 64**2
Out[56]: 4096
```

всего таких дубликатов:

```
In [29]: len(list(a**b for a in range(2, 101) for b in range(2, 101))) - len(set(a**b for a in range(2, 101) for b in range(2, 101)))
Out[29]: 618
```

---

Наивная, без попыток оптимизации, реализация (вычислительная сложность: `O(n^2)`):

```
res = len(set(a**b for a in range(2, 101) for b in range(2, 101)))
print(res)
# 9183
```

встроенный тип - `множество` (`set`) гарантирует уникальность элементов и сам удалит все дубликаты.

Comment: То есть,просто сделав список множеством я избавлюсь от дубликатов) Благодарю за ответ, не могли бы Вы дать какие нибудь советы начинающему Python Developer-у? Может какую литературу читать?

Comment: @PythonLearner4823, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python