# Книги для изучения Python

Tags: python, книги

Посоветуйте книги для изучения Python с нуля

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: вот например: - A Byte of Python - Программируем на Python (Майкл Доусон, 2013)