# Подскажите как распределить данные в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, логика

Я пытаюсь собрать технические данные определленных машин.

Есть марка машины (напр. Audi, BMW, Honda), ее модели (A1,A2,Q7,X5,X6, E70 и т.д), а также поколения моделей (2005, 2008, 2012), и технические данные определенной модели, каждого поколения. (Diesel, Bensin, Tank, Сonsumption). как мне это все это запихнуть в массив или словарь. и как манипулировать этими данными.

```
car_names = ['BMW','Audi']
car_models = ['A1','A2','X5']
car_gens = ['2004','2010','2012']
car_specs = ['Diesel','Bensin','Gas']
arr = {'car_name': car_names, 'car_models': car_models, 'car_generations': car_gens, 'car_specs': car_specs)
```

Не могу вкурить как должно все это выглядить, в php есть вложенные массивы, но тут не получается понять как управлять этим

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/204271)

Comment: вообще никак не помогло

Comment: я думаю вам стоит почитать учебники (с примерами) о реляционных базах данных, о том как там устроены связи между таблицами и о том как создавать модели данных...[Вот вам пример](https://www.autoscout24.ru/utochnitpoisk?sort=price&desc=0&ustate=N%2CU&atype=C) - поиграйтесь с ним и подумайте как там устроены зависимости

Comment: в базу загнать не проблема. перед этим мне надо все это в переменной. а как это все должно быть ? в массиве который имеет набор массивов в которых тоже наборы массивов в них уже технические данные или как?

Comment: сначала надо понять что загонять в базу, поэтому и советую вам о создании моделей данных почитать

Comment: да зачем мне сейчас про базу читать, мне нужно понять как выставить в переменную все данные. данные беруться с сайта. парситься все и заганяется в переменную, а потом уже в саму базу. а потому уже другие действия. по этому я не могу понять как они (данные) должны быть выставленны в массиве чтобы все это в кашу не превратилось. поотому, что там марка машины, ее все модели, все ее поколения и тех данные каждого поколения

Comment: желаю вам удачи !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой Вариант решения

```py
car_variants = [['BMW','Audi'],['A1','A2','X5'], ['2004','2010','2012'],['Diesel','Bensin','Gas']]
```

С помощью первого индекса извлекается целая строка (в
действительности - вложенный список), а с помощью второго извлекается элемент
этой строки:

```py
           matrix[1]
[BMW,Audi]
           matrix[1][1]
Audi
           matrix[2][0]
A1
```

Comment: спасибо вы вроде меня кинули в правильное русло, давно не кодил.  А что, если это перевести в словарь? 

{  
 "Audi": 
  { "A1": 
   { 
    "2003":['BensinOrDiesel'],
      "2008":['BensinOrDiesel']
  },
 },
 "BMW":
  { "X3": 
   {
    "2002":['BensinOrDiesel'],
    "2006":['BensinOrDiesel']
   },
  },
}