# С чего начать программировать?

Tags: php, python, pascal, basic

Объективно:

Знание английского у меня такое себе. Могу понять, более-менее могу на нем говорить, но далеко-далеко не свободно.

Начать изучение с comp. science? Может быть с PHP или какого-нибудь Паскаля? Ибо в программировании я ну совсем не шарю, но еще раз попробовать бы хотелось.

Почему еще раз? Изначально я пытался, но после забил хер, ибо было сложно и ни черта не выкупал. Да что уж там говорить, я даже не шарю за переменные, я даже не знаю шо це таке :D

Поэтому хотелось бы узнать с чего начать лучше всего. Опять же, в программировании я ноль. Нужно изучать с самого нуля. Ибо, как я сказал выше, я даже не знаю что такое переменные. И да, также не забуду сказать, что математику тоже знаю довольно плохо. Но и математику было круто изучать, но не нудно, как в школе, а например канал на ютубе, объясняющий все на простом языке и с юморком.

Прошу не писать желчью типа: "Тебе здесь не место, ты не шаришь ни черта, что да как" и пр. гадость. Просто объективно с чего начать.

Проблема ещё в том, что я не знаю, что такое алгоритмы, синтаксис и пр. Эти необходимые для программиста знания я получу в ходе обучения? Какие книжки лучше читать уж для совсем чайников в программировании?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, стоит поставить перед собой цель. Например, есть фронтенд и бэкенд. То есть передняя часть приложений(для этого есть `HTML`+`CSS`), та, что видна пользователю, и та, что отвечает за остальную логику приложения(`Node.js`/`Go`/`Python`/`PHP`). Есть, например, языки, что лучше подходят для обработки данных(`R`), а есть те, что для быстрого написания программ, где быстродействие и надежность кода отходят на второй план(`Python`).

Если же нет никаких идей по поводу того, что именно интересует, тогда могу посоветовать начать с `Python`, который довольно приятен для новичков простым синтаксисом. Это высокоуровневый язык, а значит можно обучаться, не сталкиваясь с проблемами утечки памяти и всякого такого.

Для начала главным будет являться не конкретный язык, а основы программирования. Далее надо выбирать свой путь и подбирать те ЯП, у которых есть свои преимущества в рамках вашего пути.

Вся необходимая информация для начала есть в сети. Основной ресурс программиста — интернет. Ответы на все вопросы там уже есть, а если нет, то есть такие места, как Стаковерфлоу.
Не обязательно учится по книгам, можно делать это по интерактивным самоучителям, решая задачи, параллельно находясь в поиске средств для решений или проходить онлайн курсы на Степике или Курсере.
Для вышеупомянутого `Python` можно зайти сюда [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python/420126#420126)

Comment: Я бы добавил - нужна конкретная задача, которую нужно решить. Задачки, разбор примеров - это всё хорошо, но без прикладывания этого на практический проект всё изученное будет забываться. Поэтому сперва - "хочу сделать ... ", а потом уже примеры-задачки для решения вопроса "как сделать". Субъективное мнение.

Comment: Опять же зависит от того, что именно интересно. Но я уже начал агитировать за Питон, так что могу сказать о нём. На Питоне можно делать ботов для мессенджеров(Telegram/VK), можно делать сайты при помощи Django, обрабатывать разную информацию с сайтов. Как цели для новичка могу посоветовать сделать несколько игра с PyGame или, например, ботов в используемом мессенджере, тк это можно будет использовать в повседневной жизни

Answer (score 1):

Хочу добавить свои пять копеек к ответу Dareten'а.

#### Нужно выучить английский

Это, так сказать, must have. Вся хорошая литература первой издается на английском. Некоторая *никогда* не переводится. В качестве примера могу привести ["Комментарии Лайонса к 6-й версии UNIX, с исходным кодом"](http://worrydream.com/refs/Lions%20-%20A%20Commentary%20on%20the%20Sixth%20Edition%20UNIX%20Operating%20System.pdf). Книга вышла в 76м, но я ни в первый раз (когда искал), ни сейчас, не нашел версии на русском.

Я уверен, что можно программировать и не зная английского, но в итоге все-равно придется его учить и применять.

#### Курсы

> Сейчас будет однобокое представление, основанное на личном опыте

Лично я не люблю курсы (лет пять назад я пробовал codecademy), так как там показывают *что* делает язык, а не *как*. Там вас обучат писать `int i`, чтобы создавать целые переменные и `float f`, чтобы дробные. Но что происходит "под капотом" вам вряд ли скажут.

Когда вы разберетесь в одном языке, вам легче будет понять, как работают остальные. Тогда уже можно будет пользоваться чем-то вроде [этого](https://github.com/adambard/learnxinyminutes-docs/tree/master/ru-ru), чтобы быстрее "вникнуть" в суть, а не читать книжки, которые медленно объясняют, как работает абсолютно идентичный механизм другого языка.

#### Практика

Найдите лабораторные работы какого-нибудь вуза по программированию, они дают полезные практические задачи соответственной сложности.

Если мотивации делать что-то "в пустоту" нет, то можете попробовать раздел [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) этого сайта. Сначала напишете решение большим, потом постепенно будете его сокращать, что поможет вам лучше понять, как работает язык. Главное, чтобы погоня за коротким кодом не обернулась плохими привычками в написании реальных программ, так что советую обратиться к этому варианту после некоторой практики.

P.S Только не думайте, смотря на различные решения, что люди так пишут их такими прямо из головы. Они тоже сначала создают версию, соответствующего функционала, а потом постепенно ее уменьшают

Answer (score 0):

(Python3) Книги очень много книг, Эрик Меттиз подойдет, Документация, и видео курсы на ютуб хватит на первое время. Желаю удачи в изучении этого замечательного языка)

Answer (score 0):

Мой выбор такой для сайтов: html, css, php, js.
Курсы можно найти, и вопрос только в способности уделить время для изучения.
Из курсов Специалист бауманки, webfomyself, Русаков. Иные тоже не плохи есть - это просто предпочтения.
Также очень желательно для full stack для себя овладеть фотошопом, иллюстратором, ну, и видео немного бы хорошо.
Из баз - sqlite3 отличное решение для небольших проектов - немного по ней что узнать.
Среды разработки - тут на выбор, много хорошего и бесплатного и разного, из продвинутых ide рекомендовал бы phpstorm + notepad++ для оперативной подработки.
Вообще это путь без конца - юзабилити, дизайн, концепции, технологии и решения - главное идти, понемного, но все время -для себя. Имхо.