# Порекомендуйте как начать изучать python новичку и какой редактор кода использовать

Tags: python

Порекомендуйте как начать изучать python новичку и какой редактор кода использовать
Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: как редактор возьмите PyCharm + Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 1):

Учебник "A Byte of Python" (Укус Питона), англоязычный бесплатный учебный сайт: https://www.sololearn.com/Course/Python/,
встроенный редактор IDLE (Python 3.7) - для начала.