# Как самому изучить пайтон/Python

Tags: python

Как самостоятельно изучить школьнику (15 лет) Питон?
Есть-ли какие-то сайты для этого? Где можно решать задания или работать с языком.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python Попробуйте еще на бесплатном stepic.org пройти курс по питону

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @gil9red и рекомендую stepik, а именно этот курс https://stepik.org/course/67/syllabus.