# re python для первого совпадения

Tags: python, python-3.x

нужно регулярное выражение которое из строки`C:\Users\User\Downloads\ 47798 (14)` извлечёт все кроме первого пробела. В этой строке, `C:\Users\User\Downloads\` всегда не изменно.
Пытался сделать с помощью split и replace, но эти методы для всех совпадений, а не только первого.
Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно просто убрать из строки первый пробел?

Comment: Да, именно это мне и надо

Comment: Для этого не обязательно использовать регулярные выражения. Если решение без них устраивает - могу ответить

Comment: Конечно устраивает

Comment: Просто в некоторых ситуациях для учебных задач ставят ограничения) Например, могла быть подобная задача, где решить нужно именно через регулярки, поэтому и переспросил

Comment: У вас нет пару ссылок для изучения этого?

Comment: Если хотите подробнее изучить python - вам поможет эта тема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125. Я изучал Python по видеоуроку (благо, хороших уроков сейчас немало на ютубе), это тоже неплохой вариант. Если интересует - поищите на ютубе `Python за час`. А более тонкие моменты приходят с практикой :)

Comment: Про `split` документацию не дочитали, там счетчик есть, сколько "разрезов" сделать, т.е.  `"".join(s.split(' ', 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Python есть такая чудная штука, как срезы строк, которая хорошо подходит для подобных ситуаций. Вот так можно решить эту задачу без регулярок:

```py
s = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\ 47798 (14)'
print(s[0:s.find(' ')] + s[s.find(' ')+1:len(s)])
```

Результат:

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\47798 (14)
```

Мы находим индекс первого пробела и просто склеиваем то, что было до него и то, что было после него.