# Правила хорошего тона в Python

Tags: python, оформление, хороший-тон

В один момент написания кода, на 400-ой строке, я понял, что держать все классы и функции в одном файле, возможно, является плохим тоном, и нужно делить это всё на другие файлы, импортируя друг в друга. Ближе к вопросу: где можно почитать про "хороший тон" в Python, и оформления кода в нескольких файлах (если требуется)? Буду благодарен за ссылки!

Comment: Советую посетить этот [сайт](https://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/)

Comment: Это касается не только Python, но и вообще любого языка программирования, так что можно почитать любую существующую книжку про архитектуру ПО, чистый код, паттерны программирования и т.п. (а лучше все такие книжки, чтобы стать первоклассным специалистом)

Comment: Если совсем кратко, разносить классы и функции по файлам и модулям стоит по их смыслу: конфигурация в одном файле, работа с БД в другом файле, бизнес-логика в третьем файле, парсер в четвёртом файле, отправка email в пятом файле и т.п. Идеально будет, если отдельный файл/модуль можно будет взять и без изменений использовать в другой программе (например, та же отправка email вряд ли сильно отличается в разных программах и скорее всего можно везде использовать одну и ту же функцию для отправки)

Comment: "Чистый код" Роберта Мартина.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: Смотри PEP-8 и соответствующие linter'ы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за вопросов лаконичности и качества кода был составлен специальный свод правил PEP8. Прочитать его можно здесь [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html).

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за комментарии! Я соединю всё воедино, для удобства остальным.

Разносить классы и функции по файлам и модулям лучше по смыслу, к примеру:
Работа с БД, Основная логика, Отправка email, и т.д.

И лучше делать их независимыми друг от друга, таким образом, чтобы можно было использовать и в других программах (к примеру, отправку на email).

Почитать подробнее именно про Python можно [здесь](https://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/)

Это так же касается остальных языков программирования, поэтому можно почитать любую существующую книжку про архитектуру ПО, чистый код, паттерны программирования и т.п
Например, "Чистый код" Роберта Мартина.