# Объясните как работает программа

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Она находит единственное неспаренное число в массиве , объясните как она работает

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        x=0
        for i in nums:
            x^=i
        return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^ — побитовая сумма по модулю 2 (XOR).

Вот её таблица истинности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта операция обладает коммутативностью и ассоциативностью. Т.е. не важно, в каком порядке и с какой стороны подставлять значения. Из таблицы также следует, что

```
a ^ a == 0
a ^ 0 == a
```

Поэтому для тех элементов, которые имеют пару, в результате получится ноль. Останется побитовая сумма по модулю 2 непарных элементов. Если такой элемент один в массиве, то он и получится.

Comment: а почему мы с i 'x^=i' это делаем?

Comment: i — это очередной элемент списка.

Comment: А вы не знаете где найти подробную информацию по циклам for

Comment: @dopefresh, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420126/235436. Можете ещё поискать по запросу "python цикл for" в поисковой системе google.