# Как создать графический интерфейс для программы на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, python-3.6

Как настроить gui в классическом приложении python?

пример:

- "шапка приложения" - верхняя полоса красного цвета, идет от правого угла к левому, занимает в высоту 1/4 окна приложения.
- "боковая полоса" - полоса голубого цвета находящаяся в левой стороне экрана, в высоту занимает место между "шапкой приложения" и нижней границей окна приложения. в ширину 1/4 от окна приложения.
- "основной фон" все оставшееся место занимает белый фон.
- "Заголовок" - Текстовый блок, располагающийся в левом верхнем углу. Размер текста:блок на пересечении "шапки приложения" и "боковой полосы".
- "кнопки главных разделов" - 2 кнопки располагающиеся на "шапке приложения", расположены по всей длине "шапке приложения". При нажатие по кнопке "1 раздел" или "2 раздел", меняются кнопки на "боковой полосе" в зависимости от выбора.
- "кнопки боковой полосы (при выборе "1 раздел")" - при нажатии на кнопку "1 раздел" в " боковой полосе" менялись кнопки на "1 текст", "2 текст", "3 текст".
- "кнопки боковой полосы(при выборе "2 раздел") - при нажатии на кнопку "2 раздел" в "боковой полосе"
  менялись кнопки на "4 текст", "5 текст", "6 текст".
- "1 текст (и остальные так же)" - просто длинный текст в блоке "основной фон"

Это пример приложения-сайта.

Comment: Стандартный модуль idlelib отвечает за консоль. Пошарьтесь по python/Libs/idlelib. В особенности файл idle.py(pyw), на который настроен ярлык запуска консоли. Там все можно подредактировать.

Comment: я не спрашиваю как отредактировать консоль, я спрашиваю как написать программу с пользовательским интерфейсом без прибегания к Visual studio, pycharm и тп

Comment: @СергейПрокофьев см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420126 раздел "Библиотеки для реализации графического интерфейса (GUI)". Во всех 4 вариантах можно хоть в блокноте писать.

Comment: простите двоешника, но что есть классические приложения ? и не классические ?

Comment: Попробуйте Kivy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте утилитку PyQt designer. Там Вы сможете "нарисовать" своё приложение и скомпилировать код.

Comment: хорошее предложение `+`