# Создание одномерного массива из случайных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Задача:

> Создайте одномерный массив из случайных 10 значений.

Нашёл в интернете код для создания такого массива:

```
N = 10
r_array = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(N)]
print(r_array)
```

Ответ вроде правильный, но никак не могу понять как действует код. К примеру, почему используется символ "_" после for? И можно ли написать решение проще?

Comment: Ваши вопросы показывают, что Вы не прочитали ничего про язык, а действуете методом тыка. Познакомьтесь с базовым синтаксисом, тогда легче будет искать ответы на свои вопросы - да хотя бы правильно гуглить.

Comment: [`_`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/10941639) (тыкабельно) - чтобы не плодить лишних переменных.

Comment: @MBo Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, пособия по основам Питона, если не затруднит. Я только начал осваивать язык, читаю школьную литературу по нему, но нюансов очень много и без помощи от знающих этот язык очень тяжело. Как я теперь понял, этот форум не совсем для новичков?

Comment: [Вот есть тема, где собрано много чего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-python). Лутц хорошо пишет, Саммерфилд вроде тоже.

Comment: Думаю, Вас отправят [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python). По своему опыту - я учил язык на конкретных задачах. Придумывал себе задачу - пытался реализовать её на питоне, при этом много гуглил. После этого уже начал пытаться разбираться в готовых модулях, гуглил непонятные места в их коде. И вот так итеративно, не читая каких-либо книжек, а только чужой код и офф. документацию.