# Перевод кода с Python на C++

Tags: python, c++

есть код на Python необходимо написать его же на с++, знания в python = 0, а задние необходимо выполнить, к сожалению сроки и занятость не позволят изучить python на нужном уровне.
Сложность возникает в переводе самой логики работы кода

```
            def calc_hash(proc_name):
                result = 0
                for c in proc_name:
                    if ord(c) < ord('A') or ord(c) > ord('Z'):
                        b = ord(c)
                    else:
                        b = ord(c) + 0x20
                    result = (0x19660D * result + b + 0x3C6EF35F) & 0xFFFFFFFF
                return result
             
            proc_name = (input('input:'))
            hex_out = ""
            hex_out = calc_hash(proc_name)
             
            print("IS", hex_out)
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: 0-вые знания в python

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
знания в python = 0
```

данный код:

1. выводит на экран текст `input:`
2. и ждет ввода строки
3. после чего по строке вычисляется хэш
4. хэш выводится на экран как `is <хэш>`

Сам хэш считается по следующему алгоритму:

1. проходим по всем буквам строки
2. если буква лежит вне диапазона `A..Z`, то накапливаем хэш по формуле

   ```
    result = (0x19660D * result + (int)c + 0x3C6EF35F) & 0xFFFFFFFF
   ```
3. если буква лежит в диапазоне `A..Z`, то накапливаем хэш по формуле

   ```
    result = (0x19660D * result + (int)(c + 0x20) + 0x3C6EF35F) & 0xFFFFFFFF
   ```

если в c++ знания != 0, то этого должно быть достаточно для перевода кода

**P.S.**

от себя могу добавить, что если будете работать с `unsigned int` то делать `& 0xFFFFFFFF` совершенно бессмысленно - ни на что не влияет