# Принцип работы yield в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, генераторы

Столкнулся с очень странным выводом при запуске кода:

```
def magic():
    raise RuntimeError
    print("bar")
    yield 100

print(magic())
```

и будет неожиданный для меня ответ:

```
<generator object gen at 0x7fb3073f0f68>
```

---

Вопрос немного обобщенный, хотелось бы понять как это реализовано в python и как понять на уровне кода отличия между обычной функцией и генератором?

---

потому как тип у генератор не отличается от обычной функции

```
def no_magic():
    pass

type(magic) is type(no_magic)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Схематично работа генератора выглядит так.

Функция возвращает собственно генератор, т.е. специальный объект, который хранит "текущее состояния" выполнения. Это состояние в себя включает место в функции генератора (т.е. команду `yeild`), где остановилось предыдущее выполнение.

При вызове `next` с параметром возвращенным вызовом `magic()` запускается собственно код `magic` и когда доходит до `yield`, то в этом месте значение, которое передано как аргумент в `yield` вернется из `next`. Вот пример с разметкой шагов, которые показывают порядок выполнения:

```
# я изменил функцию, чтобы продемонстрировать работу yield
def magic():
    yield 100  # шаг 3
    yield 200  # шаг 7
    print(1)   # шаг 11
    yield 300  # шаг 12
    print(2)   # шаг 16

gen = magic()  # шаг 1
a = next(gen)  # вызов next - шаг 2, присвоение - шаг 4
print(a)       # шаг 5, выведет в консоль 100
a = next(gen)  # вызов next - шаг 6, присвоение - шаг 8
print(a)       # шаг 9, выведет в консоль 200
a = next(gen)  # вызов next - шаг 10, присвоение - шаг 13
print(a)       # шаг 14, выведет в консоль 300
next(gen)      # вызов шаг 15, исключение StopIteration - шаг 17
               # т.к. magic закончила выполнение
```

Т.е. каждый раз при вызове `next(gen)` (а именно так происходит итерация по генератору) выполнение функции возобновляется с предыдущей точки `yield` и доходит до следущей, где происходит запоминание этой новой точки и возврат значения в вызывающую функцию.

Что касается типов, то тип `magic` и `no_magic` тот же - `function`. Важно что возвращает функция:

```
>>> type(magic())
<type 'generator'>
>>> type(no_magic())
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Сам код `no_magic` выполняется непосредственно в точке вызова `no_magic()`, у `magic()` этого не происходит, вызов отложен или еще по другому говорят, что вычисления делаются "лениво" или "по требованию"(lazy или on demand).

Answer (score 4):

[Описание:](https://webdevblog.ru/vvedenie-v-generatory-python/)

> Генераторы — это функции, которые можно приостанавливать и
> возобновлять во время их выполнения, при этом они возвращают объект,
> который можно итерировать. В отличие от списков, они ленивы и поэтому
> работают с текущим элемент только по запросу. Таким образом, они
> намного эффективнее используют память при работе с большими наборами
> данных.

---

Генераторы возвращают значение через оператор `yield`.

А так вы генератор вы создали через `magic()`, но вы его не выполнили.

Например так:

```
def magic():
    raise RuntimeError
    print("bar")
    yield 100

gen = magic()
print(gen)
print(next(gen))
```

Comment: спасибо, но можно развернуть ответ иобявнить как это реализованно? интересует реализация, удивило что наличие `yield` так сильно мменяет повидение функции

Comment: даже еслизаменить `raise` на `return` или `exit` поведения не измениться

Comment: @devnull, об этом лучше расскажут книги :) Добавил вырезку в ответ про генераторы

Comment: есть рекоминдации по книжкам? : ) не находил которые хорошо раскрывают тему как Python работает с памятьсю и как создает там обекты типа функции или генераторов

Comment: @devnull, у нас есть по этому вопросу специальная тема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/ :)

Comment: к сожалению не увидел там про пизкоуровневую реализацию в python

Comment: @devnull, вряд ли есть книги про низкоуровневую реализацию. Для этого смотрите в реализации интерпретаторов питона, например https://github.com/cython/cython и https://github.com/python/cpython