# Как выбрать дальнейший курс обучения?

Tags: python

посоветуйте, пожалуйста, по поводу куда двигаться далее в обучении. Уже 11 месяцев изучаю Python и английский язык, читал про "внутреннюю" работу Python и некоторые его "фишки", было дело с некоторыми базовыми библиотеками и библиотеками Numpy, OpenCV; решал задачи, затронул немного ООП. Готовых проектов по пальцам пересчитать. В будущем хочу работать с нейронными сетями, машинным обучением, ИИ и тому подобными. Нужно больше практики, но многие проекты, приходящие на ум, затрагивают библиотеку с интерфейсом(некоторые даже без интерфейса довольно трудные), PyQt5, которая сама по себе не очень трудная, но возникает проблема с разделением всей программы на классы(передача объектов другому классу и т.д.), а работа с классами очень трудна для меня, как и ООП. Не хочется переходить к изучению тем по машинному обучению, ИИ.. пока не знаю хорошо основы (к примеру, ООП и сам Python).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/400096

Comment: Посоветовать только относительно питона, или вообще?

Comment: @Neomaster, вообще

Answer (score 2):

Это лишь мое мнение!

Работодатели стремятся брать на работу человека с разносторонними навыками, это в первую очередь показывает желание и УМЕНИЕ человека справляться с новыми и уникальными задачами. Большим плюсом является наличие в портфолио проектов различного типа – зоопарка, как говорят, и лучше из диковинных животных (даже если это вымерший динозавр, то все равно это целый динозавр - круто!).

Если вы избрали путь Front-End, то вам нужно изучать CSS, JavaScript, адаптивную верстку. Тут лучше подскажут фронтэндщики.

Если вы избрали Back-End, то на вашем месте я бы стал изучать уже какой-либо компилируемый язык (Java; C# -> ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core; C++). Важно подружиться с БД, т.к. бизнес-логику в больших проектах принято реализовывать в виде пакетов хранимых процедур. Например, MySQL, PostgreSQL – если планируете идти в коммерцию; PL/SQL – в корпорацию и др. Если у вас уже есть опыт создания серьезных приложений на любом языке, то самая пора изучать принципы проектирования архитектуры ПО (DDD, SOLID и т.д.), это уже уровень >= middle.

Answer (score 2):

А что советовать?  Вот вам  (см. рисунок ниже) один из возможных RoadMap. Выбирайте, чего вы еще не знаете, и вперед.

Хотя сам принцип - сначала понаизучать всего чего можно, а потом начать применять -  мне кажется несколько ущербным. Изучение должно обязательно подкрепляться выполнением каких-либо проектов, и именно они должны диктовать, что вам надо доучивать в тот или иной момент. А изучить "все", да еще и "про запас" - все равно никогда не получиться.

А машинное обучение - это вообще не про Python. Он там лишь инструмент, причем большая часть того, что входит в "полный курс Python" и что вы уже наизучали - там в общем-то и не нужно.  И это - один из примеров того, что надо изучать инструмент под конкретную задачу. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить про машинное обучение посмотрите на текущие фреймворки Tensorflow, PyTorch и другие актуальные. В процессе поймете что будет нужно. Числодробилки типа Pandas и NumPy. Если серьезно углубляться то математика алгоритмы и тд. PyQt в текущем контексте (имхо конечно) не так и важен это отрисовка интерфейса а Вам больше нужны таблицы, данные и тд. Jupiter на первых порах (да и поздних тоже) справится с большинством задач по визуализации данных.
P.S. Ну и классы не должны быть трудными на фоне всего остального это как 2+2. А не зная это идти разбираться в высшей математике как то не правильно.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить: Вы действительно считаете, что  знание Tensorflow, PyTorch делает из человека специалиста по машинному обучению? И еще - почему "не зная этого"  разбираться в высшей математике не правильно? Как знание любой из перечисленных тем  -  ну, к примеру, тех-же классов -  поможет в изучении "математики"?

Comment: @passant Как база для старта прекрасные фреймворки. Знание классов никак не поможет в математики что как бы очевидно правда? Но их не знание не позволит временами понимать код да и вообще пользоваться  языком. Думаю это тоже очевидно...