# Как сделать программу с повторами, которая сможет создавать новые переменные?

Tags: python

Суть программы - пишешь число, которое означает сколько раз спрашивать пользователя, а программа спрашивает(например пять раз) про что-то и записывает всё в отдельные переменные.
Например :

```py
value = input("Сколько раз спросить?")
if value == "3" :
    one = input("Данные : ")
    two = input("Данные : ")
    three = input("Данные : ")
    print (one, two, three)
```

Только вместо трёх, программа выполняет input столько раз, сколько попросил пользователь

Comment: Зачем записывать всё в отдельные переменные? Вы уверены, что Вам нужно именно это, а не использование списка, например?

Comment: А как их в этом случае использовать? Просто я в питоне многого не знаю.

Comment: В теории создать новые переменные можно через `exec` или словари `globals`, `locals`. Но **НЕ** нужно так делать.

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Answer (score 2):

Фактически Вам не требуется создавать новые переменные, достаточно использовать список:

```py
value = int(input('Сколько раз спросить?'))

li = []
for _ in range(value):
    li.append(input('Данные : '))

print(*li)
```

То же самое, используя списковое включение:

```py
value = int(input('Сколько раз спросить?'))
li = [input('Данные : ') for _ in range(value)]
print(*li)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, чтобы создавать новые переменные, создайте список и добавляйте туда данные.

```
value = int(input("Сколько раз спросить?")) # Переводим value в переменную типа int
data_list = [] # Создаем список, в котором будем хранить все введенные данные

for i in range(value): # Запускаем цикл, который будет выполнятся столько раз, сколько указал пользователь (ВНИМАНИЕ! Цикл идет не с 1 до value, а с 0 до value-1)

    input_data = input("Данные: ") # Получаем то, что ввел пользователь
    data_list.append(input_data) # Вставляем это в конец списка data_list
```

Теперь есть 2 варианта вывести полученный список.
1 вариант:

```
print(data_list) # В таком случае выведется весь список. Выглядеть он будет примерно так: ['Это данные с первого воода', 'А это данные со второго воода', 'Ну а это данные с третьего ввода', 'И так далее']
```

Либо же вы можете снова пройтись циклом по списку и вывести каждый элемент отдельно:

```
for i in data_list:
    print(i, end = ' ') # end = ' ' нужен для того, что бы после вывода элемента не было переноса на новую строку.
```

Во втором случае вывод будет примерно таким:

```
Это данные с первого воода А это данные со второго воода Ну а это данные с третьего ввода И так далее
```