# Здравствуйте. Мне нужна помощь в написании кода. Мне нужно в одномерном массиве вычислить сумму значений массива с нечетными индексами

Tags: python

```
#Произвадим ввод библиотек математики и рандома
from math import*
from random import*
#Здесь производим вывод надписи на экран и попутно элемент для вычисления
n=int(input("Введите количество элементов в массиве: " ))
#Вводим пустой массив
arr=[]
#Производим ввод массива (я взял массив от -15 до 15)
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(randint(-15,15))
    #Производим показ получившегося массива
print(arr)
min=arr[0]
#Зададим в 2 единицы для вычисления
#Одну из них берем за 0
k=0
j=1
#Пишем условие для j
x=j%2==0
#В последней строке не уверен что она правильная
```

Comment: а в чем вопрос? вы привели типичное задания для начинающих изучать питон

Comment: Вопрос в том, что я не понимаю как написать этот массив

Comment: В таком случае вам стоит начать с [учебников по основам Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125)

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы пользователь ввёл массив?

Comment: Я прошу помощи. То есть да, я прошу чтобы пользователь ввел массив.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, дальше попробую сам

Comment: Помог ответ? Поставьте "лайк", галочку

Answer (score 1):

> Я прошу помощи. То есть да, я прошу чтобы пользователь ввел массив. –

```
data = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

в данном случае пользователь через пробел вводит совокупность чисел

Answer (score 0):

```
massiv=[]
for i in range(int(input())): massiv.append(int(input()))
```

Теперь пользователь *сам* вводит массив.
Сначала введите количество элементов, затем эти элементы.

Comment: с `remove` и `append` можно наворотить дел новичку, лучше пересобрать новый массив не меняя элементы старого

Comment: Да, я удалил, прошу прощения)