# Вывод элементов списка словарей по нескольким условиям

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, список

Я новичoк в Python, помогите решить задачу, застрял
У вас есть информация по пользователям, которая хранится в users_info. Каждый элемент списка — это словарь с данными пользователя.

Выведите имена и id всех пользователей, удовлетворяющих следующему условию: возраст больше 35 лет, в браке и без детей.

```
users_info = [
  {'id': 111, 'name': 'Ирина', 'age': 40, 'has_children': False, 'is_married': True}, 
  {'id': 121, 'name': 'Надежда', 'age': 20, 'has_children': False, 'is_married': False},
  {'id': 131, 'name': 'Степан', 'age': 21, 'has_children': False, 'is_married': False},
  {'id': 141, 'name': 'Константин', 'age': 65, 'has_children': True, 'is_married': False},
  {'id': 151, 'name': 'Мария', 'age': 52, 'has_children': True, 'is_married': True},
  {'id': 161, 'name': 'Валерия', 'age': 38, 'has_children': False, 'is_married': False},
  {'id': 171, 'name': 'Александр', 'age': 29, 'has_children': True, 'is_married': True},
]
```

Comment: Нужно довабить хотя-бы пример кода где вы застрыли что-бы вам помогли, я не знаю python)

Comment: «Я новичек» — [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125)

Comment: Я понимаю, что надо пройти внутренним циклом по всем словарям, сравнивая пары 'has_children': False и 'is_married': True. Но, честно говоря что то не понимаю как реализовать

Answer (score 2):

Я никогда не изучал Python, но с помошь знания других языков я пришёл к этому решению:

```
for val in users_info:
    if val['age'] > 35 and val['has_children'] == False and val['is_married'] == True :
        print(val)
```

Comment: лучше заменить ```val['age']``` на ```val.get('age')``` и так же сделать с остальными это не ошибка просто ```val['age']``` используется когда в словаре точно будет этот ключ

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @АлексейМугуев если этот ответ ответил на ваш вопрос отметьте его полезным

Answer (score 1):

Пройдитесь по телу массива обращаясь к ключам

```
print('\n'.join([f"id : {i.get('id')} Имя : {i.get('name')}" for i in users_info if i.get('age') > 35 and not(i.get('has_children')) and i.get('is_married')]))
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но в Вашем случае выдает неверное ID. В любом случае благодарю, постараюсь разобраться как исправить

Comment: Такой вопросикm а что делает join?) из любопытсво, лень искать)

Comment: @ПростаMiha в таком случае объясню своими словами метод join переводит список в строку с разделителем который указывается в ' '

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(*[itemgetter('id', 'name')(j) for j in [i for i in users_info if (i.get('age') > 35 and i.get('has_children') ==
                    False and i.get('is_married') ==True)]])

>>> 
(111, 'Ирина')
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь