# Не работают ответы на команды

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

После нажатия /start реакции никакой.
Код:

```py
import telebot
import schedule
import time
import telegram_send

bot = telebot.TeleBot("код есть")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def reply_to(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, text="Howdy, how are you doing?")

    bot.infinity_poling()


def goodnight():
    telegram_send.send(messages=["текст!!"])


def airalarm():
    telegram_send.send(messages=["текст"])


schedule.every().day.at("22:23").do(goodnight)
schedule.every().day.at("17:50").do(airalarm)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код, поместив его в тройные апострофы ``` код  ```.

Comment: Абсолютно не понял вашу проблему. Какие команды, почему они должны работать?

Comment: И почему у вас `bot.infinity_poling()` внутри хендлера?

Answer (score 1):

Я мог бы решить Вашу проблему, но я просто посоветую Вам:

1. Не пишите на `telebot`.
2. Используйте `aiogram` ([Статья для новичков](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/quickstart/#_2)).
3. Почитать [данные материалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python).

---

С уважением, Gnifajio None

Answer (score 0):

Вытащите из хендлера `bot.infinity_poling()`

```
import telebot
import schedule
import time
import telegram_send

bot = telebot.TeleBot("код есть")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def reply_to(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, text="Howdy, how are you doing?")


def goodnight():
    telegram_send.send(messages=["текст!!"])


def airalarm():
    telegram_send.send(messages=["текст"])


schedule.every().day.at("22:23").do(goodnight)
schedule.every().day.at("17:50").do(airalarm)

bot.infinity_poling()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Бот точно заработает, но не факт что остальная часть кода будет себя хорошо чувствовать