# Расшифровка ключа и паролей Google-Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, безопасность, password

Хочу не много разобраться в коде, а именно вот в этой строчке:

```
key = base64.b64decode(matches[0])[5:]
```

Не очень понимаю, что означает [0] и [5:] и для чего они нужны. Объясните пожалуйста или скиньте ссылку, где можно почитать.

```
import base64
import os
import re
import shutil
import sqlite3

import win32crypt
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

chrome_pass = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') + r"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data"
chrome_key = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') + r"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"


def chrome():
  
        if os.path.exists(chrome_pass):
            with open(chrome_key, 'r') as f:
                matches = re.findall(r'"encrypted_key":"(.+?)"', f.read())
                key = base64.b64decode(matches[0])[5:]
                secret_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
            shutil.copy2(chrome_pass, "Logincopy.db")
            conn = sqlite3.connect("Logincopy.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT origin_url, username_value, password_value FROM Logins')
            show = cursor.fetchall()
            for origin_url, username_value, password_value in show:
                print(password_value)
                initialisation_vector = password_value[3:15]
                encrypted_password = password_value[15:-16]
                cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_GCM, initialisation_vector)
                decrypted_pass = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_password)
                decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode()
                text = origin_url + '\n' + username_value + '\n' + decrypted_pass + '\n'
                print(text)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: `key = base64.b64decode(matches[0])[5:]` -- `matches[0]` взять первый элемент (по индексу 0) из массива строк, который декодируется при помощи функции `b64decode`, и из получившейся строки берётся подстрока, начиная с индекса 5 при помощи [среза](https://code-basics.com/ru/languages/python/lessons/slices)

Answer (score 0):

`matches[0]` - функция поиска модуля `re` findall возвращает все вхождения паттерна в строку, то есть если он будет входить 1 раз то будет список с одним элементом строкой `['вот так']` и нам нужно её получить поэтому берём первый элемент списка вот так `[0]`.
`[5:]` - Первые 5 символов ключа это DPAPI они будут мешать расшифровке поэтому мы их удаляем двоеточие означает взятие всех элементов после индекса в данном случае 5.

Comment: То есть [0] нам выводит всю строку, а [5:] удаляет первые 5 символов этой строки, верно?

Comment: @kevvler да можете почитать здесь https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Не просвятите ещё по моменту, где win.32.CryptUnprotectdata за круглыми скобками ставится [1]. Зачем это делается? В интернете нечего

Comment: @kevvler https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/win32crypt__CryptUnprotectData_meth.html в возвращаемом значении написано, что функция возвращает кортеж (описание, данные) нам нужны только данные

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз!)