# Проблемы со входом в Python

Tags: python

Стал изучать Python самостоятельно, утонул в информации, пробую с основ(алгоритмы А.Бхаргава, Т.Ф.Хирьянова) не идет, страница в день, воспроизвести в коде не могу, ну и самое главное видя задачу не могу понять как её начать решать с чего начать. Читаю Лутца, пишут практика много значит, информации прочитал много а толку нету. Есть ли какой то последовательный вход изучения языка?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Answer (score 2):

1. Начните с изучения основных концепций языка, таких как переменные, операторы, условные операторы, циклы и функции. Можете использовать для этого книги или онлайн-курсы.
2. После изучения основных концепций начните решать простые задачи, например, написать программу, которая выводит на экран числа от 1 до 10 или находит сумму чисел от 1 до 100.
3. После того как вы научитесь решать простые задачи, переходите к более сложным. Например, написание программы для анализа текста или для работы с базой данных.
4. Постоянно практикуйтесь и пишите код. Чем больше вы практикуетесь, тем лучше вы будете понимать язык.
5. Присоединяйтесь к сообществам Python, где вы можете задавать вопросы и получать ответы от опытных разработчиков(вам очень важно найти наставника, который будет помогать).

И помните, — практика ваше всё. Вы можете сколько угодно зарываться в книги и читать хоть весь день. Но всё это без практики пустая и бесполезная информация, только человеческий труд двигает этот мир.