# Программирование Python. Нужна литература

Tags: python, числа, системы-счисления

Подскажите пожалуйста литературу (которая, по возможности, ещё и в свободном доступе находится) по Python, где углубленно рассказывается о числовых типах данных (структура, иерархия чисел, системы счисления, особенности арифметических операций, системы счисления, соответствующие функции и т.д. и т.п., хочется очень подробно это изучить).

P. S.: Не предлагайте книги по типу "питон за 5 минут с нуля".

Предлагайте книги, где бы хорошо расписывалась теория с примерами. Мне не нужно лезть в практику в работе с большими программами, где это всё постепенно разрозненно изучается. Основы не нужны! Нужно углубленное!

Comment: В книгах по типу "питон за 5 минут с нуля" всё уже рассказано. Основных типов чисел всего три - int, float и complex, все операции с ними самые обычные (стоит лишь упомянуть, что int использует длинную арифметику), всё остальное это сторонние библиотеки

Comment: (ну разве что ещё decimal и fractions из стандартной библиотеки можно упомянуть, но не знаю, нужно ли)

Comment: Лутц, Лутц и еще раз Лутц. Там все очень подробно, с примерами и задачками.

Comment: И вообще-то это немножко дубликат: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python)

Comment: @Глеб, да кто такой этот ваш Лутц. Никогда не читал.

Comment: @insolor, это вы шутите так? Классика, между прочим. Топ1.

Comment: @Глеб, не шучу, вообще не изучал Python по книгам. Последнее, что по книгам изучал — наверное C++ Builder в бородатых 2000-х.

Answer (score 0):

Python. К вершинам мастерства, второе издание. Автор: Лусиану Рамальо

Comment: Это для экспертов вообще-то. Там такие дебри, что новичку лучше не заглядывать...