# помощь в решении задачи

Tags: python, алгоритм

Палиндром – это строка, которая одинаково читается как слева направо, так и справа налево.

Дан набор из n строк (1 ≤ n ≤ 105). Найдите среди них такие пары, которые при конкатенации дают палиндром. Более формально, найдите все пары (i, j) такие, что i ≠ j и строка si+sj является палиндромом.

Выведите все упорядоченные пары индексов (нумерация с единицы).

Формат ввода
В первой строке дано целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000) — количество строк.

Далее в n строках записано по одному слову.
Длина каждого слова от 1 до 10. Слова состоят из маленьких букв английского алфавита.

Пример 1.

Ввод:

```
4

a

abbaa

bba

abb
```

Вывод:

```
1 2

1 3

2 3

3 4

4 1

4 3
```

Как вычислять палиндром мне ясно, а как ввод данных выполнить в питоне? Не знаю, как правильно начать?

Может подскажет кто?

Comment: Подсказать что? В чём возникла проблема у вас?

Comment: у меня 4 строчки, то есть, n = int(input()), дальше мне необходимо строки первую строчку склеить со второй "a+abbaa" .. как это оформить?  вообще, мне бы задачу решить))))))

Comment: Прочитать [учебник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125) и затем с помощью полученных знаний оформить всё необходимое

Comment: Введите данные в список, например, `for _ in range(n): lst.append(input())`  Однако для решения  задачи с данными ограничениями простого перебора будет маловато, нужен эффективный алгоритм. Впрочем, сначала сделайте по-простому, чтобы работало.

Comment: План решения задачи: научиться вводить данные, научиться работать со строками и циклами, решить задачу наивным алгоритмом, на частном примере этой задачи понять что такое О-большое, изучить структуры для быстрого поиска строк, реализовать одну из них (trie, возможно, подойдёт), научится генерировать тестовые данные, отладить реализацию, сдать задачу. Если учить нормально, полгода-год. Если галопом по европам, за две недели. Если нанять человека, то два часа.

Answer (score 0):

Так пойдёт?

```
n = int(input()) # количество строк, которое будет введено
strokes = [] # все введённые строки
match = [] # все совпадения

for i in range(n):
    stroke = input() # строка
    strokes.append(stroke)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        if i != j:
            concat = strokes[i] + strokes[j]
            if concat == concat[::-1]:
                match.append([i+1, j+1])

for i in range(len(match)):
    print(match[i][0], match[i][1], sep = ", ")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: подскажите, вышеуказанный код можно ускорить? один тест не прошел по времени..

Comment: Вы пишете код, отвечая на вопрос "а как ввод данных выполнить в питоне"? Со всем уважением, но решение олимпиадных задач за людей, которые не знают язык - странный способ помогать.

Comment: я пытаюсь освоить язык, а в учебниках не всегда все понятно объясняют...хотел бы попасть на курсы, на которых обучают... вот и пытаюсь всеми возможными способами...

Comment: @СергейМарченко Извините, но я пока не знаю, как ускорить код. Если мне в голову придёт идея, я перепишу код.

Comment: Реально, как человеку, который не знает, как осуществляется ввод данных, разъяснить олимпиадную задачу? Такие обычно и в ЕГЭ решаются с вероятностью 5%.

Comment: @ArseniyRybasov Ну в два раза сможете ускорить, если циклы организовать разумнее? (Для олимпиады этого не хватит)

Comment: @MBo Как? (Я начинающий программист, не ругайтесь на меня)

Comment: @ArseniyRybasov Я не ругался, это подсказка. Для чего внутренний цикл по j проходит все значения с нуля? Можно ведь начать с i+1, и проверка не понядобится

Comment: @MBo Точно. Я забыл, что если я начну внутренний цикл с нуля, я в половине случаев пройдусь по уже проверенным парам. Сейчас исправлю. Готово.

Comment: @СергейМарченко Я исправил код, так он должен пройти по времени.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Исправил неправильный перевод слова "совпадение".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Больше похоже на сириусовскую задачу.

Comment: это была задача для поступления в яндекс-школу (нужны были минимальные знания по программированию (эта задача самая легкая...)). я понял, что совсем не готов...