Книги по Python для начинающего
Господа, захотел заняться питоном, есть минимальный опыт из школы, но хотелось бы уйти в профессиональную разработку.
Подскажите пожалуйста одни из наиболее хороших книг для самостоятельного изучения с самых азов, возможно с использованием дополнительных ресурсов, интересных задач и чтобы было действительно практикоориентировано)
Благодарю заранее за помощь!

Рекомендуемая литература, курсы и документация по Python (в том числе для начинающего).
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-python

Это надо было в тревоге-дубликате написать, а не в ответе.
